# How can we change the default Spring Boot login page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

We are migrating our legacy application, which runs on a deployed Java application server (Tomcat, Glassfish) to Spring Boot. The legacy application has a login JSP page which defines a form with a `action="j_security_check"` endpoint, which integrates with the application server's security infrastructure.

In the new application, we have overridden `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and can successfully use form based authentication against our LDAP server. However, we are presented with the default Spring security login page. How can we configure Spring Boot to use our original login JSP?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need spring mvc not just general spring boot to be able to serve jsp files.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Don't forget the

`.loginPage("/login").permitAll();` as you want your login page to be open to all users who try to authenticate.

Here is the documentation [spring doc custom login page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.20.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html#configuring-a-custom-login-page)

Also make sure that you have a controller  that serves your login_jsp for the path `/login`